# Saving to Ajax Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a table in HTML which takes user input and saves it to an Ajax server. When the page is refreshed, the newly-inputed text is still there. When someone on a different computer / phone, etc. views the table on my website, however, the changes that someone else had made on their device are not viewable. In other words, is there a way to allow users to dynamically edit content in a table on a website, and then make that information viewable by every person that visits the website after?

I have minimal experience in JS, so more detailed explanations would be helpful! Thanks so much! The code in HTML and CSS is attached below:

```css
td, table tr, th {
    border: 1px solid Black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WorkLog.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Work Log</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Work Log Template</h1>

 <table id=WorkLog contenteditable=true>
  <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Estimated Length</th>
      <th>Comments / Brief Summary (optional)</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="BtnPlus" value="+" /><input type="button" class="BtnMinus" value="-" /></td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
    function addRow() {
        var html = '<tr>' +
                    '<td>new item</td>' +
                    '<td></td>' +
                    '<td></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="button" class="BtnPlus" value="+" /><input type="button" class="BtnMinus" value="-" /></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
        $(html).appendTo($("#WorkLog"))
    };
$("#WorkLog").on("click", ".BtnPlus", addRow);
});
</script>
<script>
    function deleteRow() {
    var par =  $(this).closest('TR');
    par.remove();
};
$("#WorkLog").on("click", ".BtnMinus", deleteRow);
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#WorkLog").blur(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('WorkLogsData', this.innerHTML);
  });

  if ( localStorage.getItem('WorkLogsData') ) {
    $("#WorkLog").html(localStorage.getItem('WorkLogsData'));
  }
});

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `localStorage` belongs to a browser. If you want other users to see data then you have to save that data on a server side (in a DB or text file) and serve to over people.

Answer (score 1):

this not AJAX

you are saving the data in the client's browser via  localstorage
which all it does is save the data entered by the user on your local machine

to make it globally accessible you need to save the data on a DB on your server via AJAX

I would suggest you read these first:

- [getting started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)
- [saving data on server via AJAX](http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/javascript2/SavingData.html)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I completed the tutorial in the second link, yet I still am confused about how to implement the code their into my specific case. Any tips?

Comment: ok you need to save the data entered by the user on your server
how
[for saving]
onclick event fires a js function > that function will send an AJAX request to a specific URL on your server with the data entered by the user > on the server side you accept the data and save it into a mysql table
[for displaying]
get all the data from your mysql table and display it on the page